# $_GET not retriving information

Tags: php, wordpress, get

Relatively new to PHP so any help would be appreciated.

I am using `$_GET` to retrieve

> "Phone Number"

information from `page-profile.php`. I am writing the `$_GET` in `author.php`

Right now, i am not able to `$_GET` the info from `page-profile.php`. If i re-fresh the webpage (local host) it will not display the info.

Here is my code from `author.php` where i am having the trouble:

```
<li>
 <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
  <span class="text"><?php _e('Phone Number:',ET_DOMAIN);?></span>
   <span class="text-right"><?php echo $_GET["phone_number"];  ?></span>
   </li>
```

This is the code from page-profile.php

```
  <div class="clearfix"></div>

   <div class="form-group">

    <div class="form-group-control">

     <div class="form-group-control">

      <label><?php _e('Phone Number', ET_DOMAIN) ?></label>

       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone_number" name="Phone_Number" value="<?php echo $user_data->location ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Enter Phone Number. Important!', ET_DOMAIN) ?>">

      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

The final output should be displayed in the area "**Phone Number**" in this image. Text aligned to the right.

[Final Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVlKv.png)

Here's to hoping someone may help!

James.

Comment: To have data in $_GET they must be sent by form (action=get) or in url. I do not see here any of those#

Comment: Should i create global for 'phone_number' to access page-profile.php then $_GET ?

Answer (score 4):

Your current `name` attribute of your input is `name="Phone_Number"`, therefore, change your `$_GET['phone_number']` to `$_GET['Phone_Number']`.

Comment: Okay, i didn't see that mistake. I will also use Post in page-profile.php to send the data to author.php like Soheyl suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get data from another page directly !

You have to add the data to your URL :

```
http://example.com/?phon=xxxxx
```

So basically, you should create a :

```
header ("location: author.php/?phon=xxxxx")
```

Or just use POST to send data to author.php page in your page-profile.php !

Comment: AH! That makes sense. I shall use post. Thank you.